# Xerces 3.2.0 XCode project is not dropping it's libicuuc.dylib and libcurl.dylib dependency

Tags: macos, cmake, operating-system, configure, xerces-c

I try to build a newer version of the xerces library (3.2.0) on Mac OS using CMake to generate a xcode project. Before running CMake, I use configure to set some options and switch off some optional packages using the following command:

*"./configure CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" CXXFLAGS="-arch x86_64" --without-curl --without-icu --disable-transcoder-icu --disable-network --disable-netaccessor-curl"*

Then I generate the XCode project by cmake:

*cmake -B"/Users/rbartels/dev/external/xerces-c/3.2.0/proj/MacOS/XCode3/" -H"/Users/rbartels/dev/external/xerces-c/3.2.0" -G Xcode*

But the resulting project still depends on libicuuc, libicudata and libcurl. I can't run my application on a clean system without first installing those libraries.

Is there a way to get rid of the dependency? Do I need to disable more optional packages?

I tried many things, but the xerces-c-3.2.dylib keeps on requiring those libraries.